# How find & replace using wildcards with regex substitution?

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

Is there a way to use regex substitution with Excel find & replace (in the GUI)?

Using a JavaScript example, I want to do something like this:
`"John Smith".replace(/(.*)\s(\.*)/, "$2, $1") // returns "Smith, John"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an add-on at www.codedawn.com that adds regexp functionality to MS Excel's find&replace dialog. That's the answer!
Just one note: replacements made by this add-on are NOT UNDOABLE. You will be warned to save your workbook before committing replace.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for - though I was surprised its not built-in. Actual link is http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you can get similar functionality combining Excel's FIND and MID functions - note that if what you're finding (the "\s" in your example) is a wildcard also, your function will probably get very long - but it's possible.  See [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-excels-find-and-mid-to-extract-a-substring-when-you-dont-know-the-start-point/1033368) for some (fairly simple) examples.

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually looking for it in the GUI, which wasn't clear in my original question so I updated it.